# How to unzip and display as plain text .foo.gz files in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, gzip

Using Firefox (currently at version 20.0), when browsing to a URL containing a file with an extension of .foo.gz, how can I make Firefox download it to a temporary location, un-gzip it and display the result as a plain text file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox does this already for file types that are plain text when decompressed, it knows about, and when the server is correctly configured.

Opening this [diff of changes to a package on Launchpad](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/135423671/ubuntuone-control-panel_4.1.91-0ubuntu1_4.2.0-0ubuntu1.diff.gz) for example, works just fine. If you want to open other file types, such as `.tar.gz` or some other type which Firefox (and probably the local system in general) doesn't know how to deal with, you'll have to open it in an external application, which Firefox will do by downloading the file to a temporary location, and running the app with that file name as the argument to open.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The "when the server is correctly configured" was the answer. Just needed to play around with Apache mime.conf.